# Saving html data in two different mysql table with single submit button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page with some input fields and a table whose rows are dynamically generated using jQuery. I am trying to save the input fields in one mysql table and the dynamically generated rows in another. The input fields are working fine. But with dynamically generated table rows, only the first row is inserting, other roes below the first is not inserting. Here are my codes. Please tell me what am I doing wrong. Thanks a ton.
HTML FORM

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="saveFiles/savePurchase.php" method="post" target="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="invoiceNo" class="col-md-6 control-label">Invoice No.</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="invoiceNo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="supplier" class="col-md-6 control-label">Supplier</label>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <select name="supplier" class="form-control">
                            <option>SELECT</option>
                            <?php include('saveFiles/connection.php');
                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT Id,Name FROM supplier");
                                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                                    $supplierId = $row['Id'];
                                    $supplierName = $row['Name'];?>

                                    <option value="<?php echo $supplierId;?>"><?php echo $supplierName;?></option>

                            <?php  }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <img src="img/plus.png" class="pull-right" style="margin-top: 5px;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#supplierModal">
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="invoiceNo" class="col-md-6 control-label">Invoice Date</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" name="invoiceDate" readonly="readonly">
                    </div>
                </div><br><br>
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="paymentMode" class="col-md-6 control-label">Payment Mode</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select name="paymentMode" class="form-control">
                            <option>Cash</option>
                            <option>Cheque</option>
                            <option>Card</option>
                            <option>On Account</option>
                            <option>Credit</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

                <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Unit</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="addNew">Add New Row</button></th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="cloneme">
                            <td>
                                <select name="productName[]" class="form-control" style="width: 110px;">
                                    <option>SELECT</option>
                                    <?php
                                        include('saveFiles/connection.php');
                                        $selectQuery = mysql_query("SELECT Id,ProductName FROM items ORDER BY ProductName");
                                        while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectQuery)){
                                            $productId = $rows['Id'];
                                            $productName = $rows['ProductName']; ?>

                                            <option value="<?php echo $productId;?>"><?php echo $productName?></option>
                                    <?php  }
                                    ?>

                                </select>
                            </td>

                            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="unit[]"></td>
                            <td> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="qty[]"></td>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" id="save">Save</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" name="reser">Clear</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <iframe name="purchaseMsg" style="border: none; background-color: #00aceb; !important; width:0px; height:0px;"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="supplierModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Supplier</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <form action="saveSupplier" method="post" target="categoryMsg">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newSupplier" placeholder="Add New Supplier">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        </div><br>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success"value="Save" id="saveSupplier" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Clear">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And this is my php script to insert the form.

```
<?php
include('connection.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $invoiceNo = $_POST['invoiceNo'];
    $invoiceDate = $_POST['invoiceDate'];
    $supplierId = $_POST['supplier'];

    $insertQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchase(InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,SupplierId) VALUES('$invoiceNo','$invoiceDate','$supplierId')");

    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    $rowData = array();
    foreach($_POST['productName'] as $row=>$itemName){
        $productName = mysql_real_escape_string($itemName);
        $unit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['unit'][$row]);
        $qty = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['qty'][$row]);



        $rowData[] = "('$productName','$unit','qty')";
    }
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO purchaseDetails(ItemName, Unit, Quantity)  VALUES".implode(',',$rowData));
}

?>
```

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: change << $rowData[] = "('$productName','$unit','qty')"; >> to <<$rowData[] = "('$productName','$unit','$qty')"; >>, you forgot a $

Comment: @AbdoAdel Sorry! That was a typing mistake. Actually I have $qty in my code but still not working

Comment: yes i know that this is not going to fix the problem, just a side note :D

Answer (score -1):

I think it might be related to the way you construct the multiple insert records, so instead of this...

```
rowData[] = "('$productName','$unit','qty')";
```

You should maybe try something like this...

```
rowData[] = "(\"".$productName."\", \"".$unit."\", \"".$qty."\")";
```

Comment: I tried your code but still only the first row is inserted.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question + it's the same output

Comment: Shouldn't you pass along to the purchaseDetails query the $id from the purchase query as well? You most definitely need a foreign key through which you can associate each row from the purchaseDetails table to a row in the purchase table.

Comment: @Filip I tried that too but still only the first row is inserting. Rest of the rows are not inserting

Comment: And the output of implode(',',$rowData) is correct? I mean is it actually a comma separated list of multiple insert records?

Comment: You know what would also help? Capture any possible mysql errors...  So just write the mysql query command like this: $query=mysql_query(sql.query.goes.here) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @Filip Doesn't show any errors. but when I `echo implode(',',$rowData)`, only the first row is showing.

Comment: There you go... so there are actually no bugs in your code, it actually does what's supposed to do :)

Comment: @Filip Then what could be the problem?. Why isn't the code inserting all the rows instead of just one?

Comment: My guess is that there's only one element in this array $_POST['productName']. Can you test please?